# Multi-Threaded Custom Cell Factory

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8, cell, controlsfx

I currently have a custom cell factory that contains videos played through javafx.scene.media. The problem is that when I add more than one video the application is laggy.

**How can I put each cell on its own thread? Are there better ways to add the video to the cell that would have each video on its own thread?**

CrontrolsFX Custom Cell Factory

```
gridView.setCellFactory(new Callback<GridView<MediaCard>, GridCell<MediaCard>>() {

        @Override
        public GridCell<MediaCard> call(GridView<MediaCard> param) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new MediaCell();
        }

    });
```

MediaCell.java

```
public class MediaCell extends GridCell<MediaCard>{

public MediaCell() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(MediaCard item, boolean empty) {

    if (item != null) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        AnchorPane rootAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();

        File f = new File(item.getPath());

        Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.play();

        MediaView mv = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        mv.setPreserveRatio(true);

        Button viewMediaButton = new Button("View");

        VBox vbox = new VBox(mv, viewMediaButton);

        DoubleProperty mvw = mv.fitWidthProperty();
        DoubleProperty mvh = mv.fitHeightProperty();
        mvw.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.parentProperty(), "width"));
        mvh.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.parentProperty(), "height"));

        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(vbox);  
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vbox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(vbox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(vbox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(vbox, 0.0);

        setGraphic(rootAnchorPane);

    }
}

}
```

Failed attempt to move each cell to its own thread

```
gridView.setCellFactory(new Callback<GridView<MediaCard>, GridCell<MediaCard>>() {

        @Override
        public GridCell<MediaCard> call(GridView<MediaCard> param) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mediaCell = new MediaCell();
                }
            }).start();
            return mediaCell;
        }

    });
```

Comment: You just have to put the start of the player ```mediaPlayer.play()``` in a new thread

Comment: @Daniel This will result in many threads. Please see my comment on your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put the mediaPlayer.play() in a new Thread

Something like:

```
public class MediaCell extends GridCell<MediaCard> {

    public MediaCell() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MediaCard item, boolean empty) {

        if (item != null) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            AnchorPane rootAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();

            File f = new File(item.getPath());

            Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                }
            }.start();

            MediaView mv = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
            mv.setPreserveRatio(true);

            Button viewMediaButton = new Button("View");

            VBox vbox = new VBox(mv, viewMediaButton);

            DoubleProperty mvw = mv.fitWidthProperty();
            DoubleProperty mvh = mv.fitHeightProperty();
            mvw.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.parentProperty(), "width"));
            mvh.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.parentProperty(), "height"));

            rootAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(vbox);  
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vbox, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(vbox, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(vbox, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(vbox, 0.0);

            setGraphic(rootAnchorPane);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in numerous threads being spawned in a unpredictable fashion. Everytime updateItem is called... frequently with cell factories... new threads are spawned.

Comment: I would say to use a common CachedThreadPool executor for all your MediaCell's

Comment: How would that solve the number of threads being spawned for each MediaCell?

Comment: Instead of creating a new thread you would submit your task to the executor and leave it handle the thread allocation. But I think I should study more the MediaPlayer class. I guess it handles the thread allocation itself, so maybe invoking the play in another thread/executor may have no effect on your problem